# Add-Migration not including my two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

For some weird reason my add-migration is not adding my two additional tables?

Here is my context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("UserAuthentication")            
    {
    }
    //Tables       
    new public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<User_Manager_Interface.Models.UserActivityLog> ActivityLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User_Manager_Interface.Models.LogAction> LogActions { get; set; }
}
```

now when i run add-migration I get the following:

```
  public partial class testr : DbMigration
  {
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
  }
```

But when I look in my database there are only the asp.net identity tables an not my two Log Tables

Comment: Roll back to a previous migration (`Update-Database -TargetMigration NameOfMigration`) and run the add-migration command again.

Comment: Any Alternatives to that? Unfortunatly I don't have any previous migrations

Comment: Try add-migration with -ConnectionString and -ConnectionProviderName switches(http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/)

Comment: Can you show us your connection string?

Comment: So strange, I have further discovered. That if I run a sql query to create this table, It says that it cannot as there is already an instance with the same name in the database? However I cant see it in sql manger studio and EF cant see it, I have dropped it in sql and recreated it and still I cannot see it?